# When we specify the chunked http response, what does it mean?

Tags: http

when we specify that the response if chunked, what does it mean?

what exactly checked mean in the http reponse?

Comment: A simple Google search leads to a nice [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) that answers the question in detail. Also see the [HTTP/1.1 Protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html) (scroll to section 3.6).

Comment: Why is this tagged with both `java` and `asp.net-mvc`?

Comment: @RichardSzalay - fixed.  It is now tagged with "http".

Comment: will chunked response be the same as normal reponse?